# Tell suspended chat users which messages were flagged

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, flags

It appears there is a *"feature" that's always existed* where I get suspended from chat for having messages flagged.

It is annoying that suspended users do not get told why they were suspended.

Can we have a list of which messages were flagged when we get suspended.

At least this way people can learn why they were suspended and not do it again in the future.

As a further aside, the fact a room owner can get suspended for flagged messages in his room is rubbing salt in my wounds.

Comment: That feature is *not* new. It has always existed.

Comment: @balpha Don't worry, I corrected the grave error.

Comment: @balpha really? I've only recently being getting suspended. And other people have been getting suspended recently. Maybe the flag limit has reduced? I think it's 3 flags and you get suspended (for an hour or two).

Comment: No, that hasn't changed either. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100414/how-many-chat-flags-are-required-to-remove-a-message-ban-a-user/100439#100439

Comment: I think that, in light of the points made by [Incognito's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102616/tell-suspended-chat-users-which-messages-were-flagged/102618#102618), a better (?) feature request would be to move the "flag" button as far away from the "star" button as possible.

Comment: See also: [Show who flagged a message in chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102622/162705)

Comment: @Chris [complied](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102623/flag-button-is-positioned-poorly-in-chat)

Comment: The most important thing being said here is that there is no feedback! Why does SE have so many user related features that don't have feedback?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This may just be Jeff's staff not listening to him: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html .

Many of these flags might just be human error because we put the FM Radio next to the Ejector Seat button.

[image]

I can tell what you're thinking. Did he click Flag or Star Now? Well, to tell you the truth, in all the excitement of reading that message, I kind of lost track myself. Good thing we can easily undo a flag'd item! **Oh wait, we totally can't.**

To make it worse, the star is *always* highlighted on mouse-over of any of these items.

Comment: "Yes, the rap button is just to the right of the radio knob.  Go ahead and press it if you like rap..."

Comment: Wow. That is a horrible, *horrible* design decision. Not only are those buttons right next to each other, but they're actually *smaller than the mouse cursor.* This is one of the most blatant violations of [Fitts's Law](http://particletree.com/features/visualizing-fittss-law/) that I've ever seen.

Comment: There's a [confirmation dialog](http://i.stack.imgur.com/chp6S.png) after clicking the flag icon, you can't really hit it accidentally.

Comment: @Brant Bobby it's new.

Comment: Oh. Well, in that case, pretend I said "there *is now* a confirmation dialog". ;)

Comment: @Brant Bobby Touche.

Comment: Please stop making up stuff when you're proven wrong. That dialog is *not* new. /cc @Brant

Answer (score 12):

OK, I ran the queries. Your must "popular" remarks are:

- (redacted) you deserve to be called an idiot for writing code like that
- (redacted) because windows is for gays. *gays*
- Look google is full of *shit*
- dont like me random shit please.
- If I want my website to look like shit then I'll ask you
- I simply consider non english language noise and spam
- *shit*
- (redacted) don't be a dick :D
- Fuck thread safety
- (redacted) Anger issues my ass!
- my f key is acting up
- (redacted) I just defined a language limitation in *this room*
- You want to speak in a foreign tongue then take it somewhere else.

where "(redacted)" is *any other user*, just to keep it context free.

I think the flags were correctly earned. My main thought now is *at what point* the system should escalate the suspension time, or whether to just keep that manual. Please remain civil in the chats; it isn't an open forum for abusing people, nor an outlet for homophobia and xenophobia.

I will, however, think about ways in which we can make the "why was I suspended" automated so there is no uncertainty. In other news, there is a secondary issue with people using flags incorrectly; in this case, I don't think that applies.

Comment: I do agree that most time's the flags were just. However it's still user friendly to identify which message causes me to be suspended. And I also raised this issue on behalf of other people who are suspended and don't know which message was flagged (and caused them to be suspended).

Comment: @Raynos granted - I'll look into that.

Comment: also apologies if I seem to be "complaining" that I was unjustly flagged. This was not the intend.

Comment: @Raynos I'll be adding something to track this

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that some people treat "flags" like an opposite for "stars". Like a *dislike* button. That could be one of the reasons why people get flagged almost randomly.

Comment: To add to this, we've seen people flag for entirely valid and useful debates such as, is LOC a valid metric for code quality, and how?

Comment: @Incognito: but the idea that LOC is a valid metric of quality is patently offensive; this is a bad example.

Comment: @Wooble , well , i got flagged for defending [UncleBob's statements about size of functions](http://cleancoder.posterous.com/clean-code-episode-iii-contents-and-release-n) .. at least that what i gathered.

Comment: @teresko: I'd certainly flag you for defending his use of white text on translucent white background, although possibly not his opinions.

Comment: .. was't that a common knowledge, that developers usually are colorblind when it comes to making a design ?

Comment: Any theories on why they do this with chat messages, but not with comments?

Comment: because when you flag comments, it asks you to elaborate, and there is no option for "i disagree".