# Suspension reasons on chat

Tags: discussion, chat, account-suspension

Arguments were made in [Avoid the Streisand Effect - be clear about the reason when suspending an account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23385) for showing a reason when a user is suspended from the main site, and as a result this was implemented. The reasons available for a main site suspension are:

> to cool down
>   because of low quality contributions
>   because of low signal to noise ratio
>   for vote abuse
>   for spamming

Any of these apart from vote abuse could apply to chat. However, on chat a suspension does not display a reason, simply

> This user has been temporarily suspended by a moderator and cannot chat for n days.

Do the same arguments lead to the conclusion that chat should show reasons too? Or is there some reason that chat should remain as it is?

---

There is a [similar sounding question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100323/please-notify-people-of-the-reasons-for-chat-suspension) but this resulted in the *source* of the suspension being displayed (parent site suspension/user flagging/manual moderator suspension), rather than a reason. I've tried to make this new question specifically about the reason.

Comment: Chat is quite different, though. We only even have the single moderator attention flag in chat (aside from a custom flag): spam/offensive. Could you identify different reasons you'd expect to see for a chat suspension other than "does not play nice in chat"?

Comment: @animuson I've edited to mention the reasons used on main, all but one of which seem to make sense on chat too.

Comment: Well, suspensions on chat are usually clear. If they're in minutes, they're because someone flagged the guy. If they're in days or hours, it's because of a manual mod suspension. I'm really meh about this. I didn't read much into the site reasons either. Just . . . Meh.