# Why was I suspended from chat for a fairly harmless message?

Tags: support, chat

I just posted this message with bold text on https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec . Immediately some one suspended me for half an hour.

Here is my message

> **MIRACLES HAPPENS WHEN YOU ACTUALLY HAVE A STRONG WILL**

Why did I get suspended for that?

Comment: And you are prepared to swear that that's the *only* thing you said in that room?

Comment: There's probably a lot  more to this than  one message.

Comment: This was possibly an automated ban. A few messages later someone posted this: *This user has been automatically suspended for posting inappropriate content and cannot chat for 28 minutes.*

Comment: He was annoying as hell throughout the whole day, posting random stuff.

Comment: Looks like you were [automatically suspended](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1042889/aairkhan) after multiple of your messages were flagged. No moderators involved there, you just managed to alienate enough people that you got booted. The suspension is temporary, but you may want to be more careful in future.

Comment: I like how playing the victim on meta always backfires.

Comment: @Ahmad Several days even. The overriding point is that there is no sensible contribution. So it's just the noise. And the spam.

Comment: **UPDATE** Recovered one of a group of message that I flagged as spam http://i.stack.imgur.com/9uFZ1.png on monday [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=15322586#15322586). He was already only coming in to drop the spam then.

Comment: "MIRACLES HAPPENS WHEN YOU ACTUALLY HAVE A STRONG WILL" *take note, intenets*

Comment: @R.MartinoFernandes Its a good thing its that way.

Answer (score 37):

You have been annoying us for two days already, and you know this. We warned you and told you to get out, but you refused to do so, and since we still have no ability to permaban people (sadly), this was the best we could do. It wasn’t necessarily about this exact message.

Comment: The amount of the user's content in the [recycle bin](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/12285) indicates as much.

Comment: "since we still have no ability to permaban people" **MIRACLES HAPPENS WHEN YOU ACTUALLY HAVE A STRONG WILL**

Comment: @Bart and that doesn't show the posts auto0deleted by Feeds (with enough validated flags)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn It's taking all of the strength of my willpower to not flag that comment.

Comment: I smell a Reversal here...

Comment: @rightfold such people are the reason we keep room 15 in gallery mode. That way you can permaban...

Comment: @WarrenFaith We have done that several times but nobody really liked it. We want blacklist mode, not whitelist mode.

Comment: I am a fan of a more controlled environment so I personally dislike every open room (based on very bad experience) but I agree, I would prefer a blacklist method and would really consider that as an gallery mode alternative...

Answer (score 32):

You had several other flagged messages:

> Ecllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllippppppppppppppppppseeeeeeeeeeeeeeee‌​eeeeeeee

and

> ## _

and

> $_$

and

> &_&

and

> TROLL_TROLL

so the

> **MIRACLES HAPPENS WHEN YOU ACTUALLY HAVE A STRONG WILL**

message was the final straw that triggered the automatic ban. These messages didn't appear to have anything to do with the conversations going on at the time in that chat room, and members must have found them to be disruptive.

You were [repeatedly asked to leave](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15389813#15389813), and a response of ["mind your own business"](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15389910#15389910) probably didn't help you any there.

The C++ Lounge may not be the best place for you to hang out.

Comment: FTR all of these were final drops in a bucket that had been filling for days now. More content provided by the user in question can be found in the "bin" and "recycle bin" rooms.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Although the actual spam adverts have been deleted by feeds.

Answer (score 9):

This was an automated ban. There's a message on [your chat profile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1042889/aairkhan):

> This user has been automatically suspended for posting inappropriate content and cannot chat for 20 minutes.

[As @Martijn said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226170/why-suspention-of-this-message#comment739995_226170), too many of your messages were flagged, resulting in this ban.

Comment: MIRACLES HAPPENS WHEN YOU ACTUALLY HAVE A STRONG WILL  is this message inappropriate?

Comment: @Aღmirkhan: That is *not the only message*, it was the last drop in a whole bucket.

Comment: I just saw you insult someone here in the comments (it's removed already), so I'm willing to bet you've done a whole lot more than just that message.

Comment: @Stijn I don't think so, after suspended period of 2.5 hour i just posted this message, it looks like SO is making partiality

Comment: After a suspension, I'm willing to bet that one's record is not cleared automatically. Getting further flags would then be tacked onto your existing record, which would trigger the automatic ban again.

Comment: @Aღmirkhan: That's because you don't get to start with a clean slate after an automatic ban. Continue to accumulate flags and you'll be banned again and again, for increasingly long periods. If not automatic, then certainly by moderator intervention.

Comment: @ChrisForrence: actually, that's not quite [how it works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86479/how-do-chat-suspensions-work), but in this case the community patience seems to have run out.